# Change height of jQuery Mobile footer buttons

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

**Scenario :**

- I have taken the footer code from the jQuery Mobile website and incorporated it into my file.
- Everything is working well until I try and change the height of the
  footer buttons.

**Todo :**

- I want the buttons to be 7.5% in height from the
  bottom, but every time I try and change it, it leaves a grey space
  underneath the buttons, and they stay the same height.

**Code :**

```
<!-- FOOTER -->
        <div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed" style="height: 7.5%;">
            <div data-role="navbar" style="height: 7.5%">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#page1">Search</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page2">Planner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#page3">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /navbar -->
        </div><!-- /footer -->
```

[image: At the bottom, the grey gap can be seen]

Comment: Is the parent element of the footer the body or a container?

Comment: It is the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure it's 7.5% of the viewport you can use 7.5vh.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-id="footer" data-position="fixed" style="height: 7.5vh;">
  <div data-role="navbar" style="height: 100%">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#page1">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page2">Planner</a></li>
      <li><a href="#page3">Jobs</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>
```

Something like that-ish.

Comment: I'm unsure how your app will react, but please let us know.

Comment: Complete beginner mistake on my part. Thank you very much, it worked!